# removing gaps between each columns in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I want to build a home page for my blog and I want to show posts like this picture (somehow like '[Dzone](http://Dzone.com)' site publications part of main page)

[image]

But, I'm getting this via bootstrap grid system:

[image]

Does anyone know how can I fix this problem?
Is it possible to have columns like this in bootstrap?

Thank you for helping me :D

Comment: You can use rows within the adjacent columns instead of using adjacent columns within stacked rows.

Comment: https://imgur.com/Q7GV7YA  . This is what I mean by previous comment.